# Does pgcluster support PostgreSQL 9.0 version?

Tags: postgresql

I am finding difficulties in finding multi-master (supports atleast 3 to 4 masters) replication package for postgresql Data Base.
Does pgcluster support postgresql 9.0 version ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the beta. If I understood correctly, synchronous master-master replication is built into PostgreSQL 9.1:

http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/release-9-1.html

E.1.3.2.1. Streaming Replication and Continuous Archiving